# I am trying to open DINO Game in chrome using python's webbrowser module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-webbrowser

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(r"C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new_tab('chrome://dino')
```

When I run this, it opens a new tab, but does not run the game.

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Drivers/network/chromedriver')
driver.get("chrome://dino")
```

You will need to set-up a [chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) for this

Comment: TY!.. I actually dont know selenium. Can you tell me how to open this as a new tab in an open chrome window...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Try This

```py
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(r"C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new_tab('https://chromedino.com/')
```

Comment: Thanks but it WON'T work for me, since I am trying to automate dino game.and I would like to use official version...

Comment: OK, I have No Possible Solution For This :_(